# Why static class type function returns zero?

Tags: c++, function

I'm reading C++ Essential handout by Stanford professor Nick Parlante.The following is a code example:

```
/* If C++ kept class name information around at run-time,
    this would be easier. */
    static Account *RandomAccount(void) {
    switch (RandomNum(3)) {
    case 0: return(new Gambler); break;
    case 1: return(new NickleNDime); break;
    case 2: return(new MonthlyFee); break;
    }
    return(0);
    }

static int RandomNum(int num) {
return(rand() % num);
}
```

My question is, why this function returns zero when the type is `Account`?Does it mean false here?

Comment: Please show implementation of function `RandomNum`.  Edit your post with the answer.

Comment: The function returns `Account*`, not `Account`.

Comment: @Falmarri I have no idea about horrible code as I'm just a beginner.But if Stanford professor writes crap code then I don't know who else I can trust as a beginner hehehe.

Comment: A 0 pointer is like "absense of".  If you say "what time is my appointment?" and the answer is "you do not have an appointment".

Comment: @Falmarri That's unduly harsh and not constructive. Focus on what's important, and mention less-important things in a nicer way, maybe? YMMV, but going after a beginner like that just seems mean-spirited.

Comment: @DaveNewton It was suggested that this code was written by a professor, not by the asker of the question. That's why I was critiquing it.

Comment: @Falmarri Critique is valuable. Meanness, not so much. As I said, YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function returns `Account*`, not `Account`. That 0 is a null pointer constant.

Comment: So just saying zero I can denote null pointer? I don't have to say NULL?

Comment: @Arnob, Please use `nullptr`. While 0 and `NULL` both work, they have issues that were motivation for `nullptr` to exist.

Comment: `nullptr` is only available in C++11 and later. In earlier versions, 0 is used instead, and `NULL` is usually just a macro for 0, eg `#define NULL 0`